# Perl regex capture each character as one group

Tags: regex, perl

I have:

```
Aenean placerat >> /example/alpha.txt
est et rutrum ultrices >> /example/beta.txt
dolor nibh ultricies nulla >> /example/gamma delta.txt
```

I need:

```
Aenean placerat >> \/\e\x\a\m\p\l\e\/\a\l\p\h\a\.\t\x\t
est et rutrum ultrices >> \/\e\x\a\m\p\l\e\/\b\e\t\a\.\t\x\t
dolor nibh ultricies nulla >> \/\e\x\a\m\p\l\e\/\g\a\m\m\a\ \d\e\l\t\a\.\t\x\t
```

Obviously this does not work, but I can't find a way to achieve this...

```
's/(.*) >> (.)*/$1 >> \\$2/gm'
```

Answer (score 4):

A quick and simple way is to apply a regex substitution inside your regex substitution.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    s/>> \K(.+)/ $1 =~ s#(.)#\\$1#gr /e;
    #            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ inner substitution
    print;
}

__DATA__
Aenean placerat >> /example/alpha.txt
est et rutrum ultrices >> /example/beta.txt
dolor nibh ultricies nulla >> /example/gamma delta.txt
```

The `/e` (eval) modifier tells Perl to evaluate the RHS as code. Note the use of alternative delimiters on the inner substitution operator `s###`, and the use of the `/r` modifier to return the value only (we can't modify a read-only variable anyway). The `\K` escape allows us to "keep" what is left of the regex match.

This can be used as a simple one-liner:

```
perl -pe's/>> \K(.+)/ $1 =~ s#(.)#\\$1#gr /e' yourfile.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

You can match every single character after the first occurrence of >> and then use `\K` to clear what is matched so far in combination with `\G` to match every single character after it.

```
(?:^.*?>>\h*|\G(?!^))\K.
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternation

  - `^.*?>>\h*` Match until the first occurrence of `>>` followed by optional horizontal whitespace chars
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the position at the end of the previous match, not at the start of the string
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `.` Match a single character

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/prVE2A/1) or a [perl demo](https://ideone.com/lJl4D1).

In the replacement use the full match preceded by `\`

Example

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    s/(?:^.*?>>\h*|\G(?!^))\K./\\$&/g;
    print;
}

__DATA__
Aenean placerat >> /example/alpha.txt
est et rutrum ultrices >> /example/beta.txt
dolor nibh ultricies nulla >> /example/gamma delta.txt
```

Output

```
Aenean placerat >> \/\e\x\a\m\p\l\e\/\a\l\p\h\a\.\t\x\t
est et rutrum ultrices >> \/\e\x\a\m\p\l\e\/\b\e\t\a\.\t\x\t
dolor nibh ultricies nulla >> \/\e\x\a\m\p\l\e\/\g\a\m\m\a\ \d\e\l\t\a\.\t\x\t
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to split the line in two, then apply the substitution only to the right side:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<DATA>) {
    my ($x, $y) = split /\s+>>\s+/;
    $y =~ s/(.)/\\$1/g;
    print "$x >> $y";
}

__DATA__
Aenean placerat >> /example/alpha.txt
est et rutrum ultrices >> /example/beta.txt
dolor nibh ultricies nulla >> /example/gamma delta.txt
```

Outputs:

```
Aenean placerat >> \/\e\x\a\m\p\l\e\/\a\l\p\h\a\.\t\x\t
est et rutrum ultrices >> \/\e\x\a\m\p\l\e\/\b\e\t\a\.\t\x\t
dolor nibh ultricies nulla >> \/\e\x\a\m\p\l\e\/\g\a\m\m\a\ \d\e\l\t\a\.\t\x\t
```